# How to implement Linux's Script command in C++

Tags: c++, linux

I have been asked to implement a shell of my own in C++. I am done with most of the things, but I want to know that how could I implement Linux's command- "script" in c++ code.I have no clue about this.

I know what the script command does.I want that same functionality in my own shell.

How do I move forward?

Comment: Are your command parsing and execution functions independent, using strings or buffers instead of hard-coded reading from the input device? Then you're basically done, and all you have to do is to be able to read the script file and split it into lines for the parsing and execution.

Comment: yes they are.where is this script file?

Comment: ‘script‘ seems to be an external command. If your shell recognizes internal commands from external ones, you will not need to do any thing special; just forward the parameters to the external command and sink the output.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. `script` forks the underlying shell, and records the input to that shell and output from it. It will also fork your shell, without needing special support.